# Cannot use Git from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git

I can use `git` fine from command line, I can use fine git from NetBeans IDE, and I can use git fine from IntelliJ IDEA.

But I cannot use `git` in any instance of Eclipse (either pure Eclipse for Java IDE, or IBM Rational Application Developer which based on Eclipse). SSH keys configured same as for other IDEs and are valid.

I suspect problem at some OS level, maybe Eclipse stores some global settings somewhere and all instance reuse them. Tried to delete `%USERPROFILE%/.eclipse` -- did not help.

The error in `.log` is like that (again, keys are valid and properly configured in SSH2 Preferences dialog in Eclipse):

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 4 0 2019-03-29 13:01:45.024
!MESSAGE git@git.assembla.com:xxx.git: git@git.assembla.com: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).

!STACK 0
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: git@git.assembla.com:xxx.git: git@git.assembla.com: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
```

[UPDATED on 04/02/19]

[image]
[image]

as you can see github.com was not even added to known hosts, i.e. it was not attempted to connect.

[image]
[image]

typical error.

[image]

command line `git` works

[image]
[image]

adding user id `git` to ssh protocol connection type does not help.

Comment: How did you exactly configure the SSH keys? In Eclipse, you have to add the private SSH keys in _Window > Preferences: General > Network Connections > SSH2_.

Comment: Correct. 
The very same keys successfully used by other applications (command line `git` and NetBeans and IDEA). And Eclipse worked too for several years, just stopped at some moment, and as mentioned -- all Eclipse instances on the system are affected, so it's not a question of Preferences, which I believe stored somewhere under workspace scope.

Comment: Eclipse uses JGit (a Git implementation in Java) whereas IDEA just delegates to the command line Git (which is not required in Eclipse). In Eclipse 2019-03 the default SSH client has become _Apache MINA sshd_. You can switch back to _JSch_ in _Window > Preferences: Team > Git_. Which EGit/JGit version do you use? Is a proxy involved? Are the SSH keys password protected and if yes, did you save the password? Are the SSH key files readable as a normal user?

Comment: Switch from Apache MINA to JSch did not do anything -- same error. I am not sure what version of EGit/JGit I use -- just downloaded the latest Eclipse 2019-03. The SSH keys are password protected for sure, and password never changed. I cannot recall if pw was saved, anyway other tools ask pw when needed, so I assume should do Eclipse. Keys are readable to user, as other tools can connect. No proxy used -- direct connection to internet. Problem occurs with different Git sites (github, assembla)

Comment: There are either tools that delegate to the Git command line and tools that use JGit. At which step exactly do you get which error? Are you asked for a password or not? Please show your _Window > Preferences: General > Network Connections > SSH2_ and the clone dialog for a public GitHub repository.

Comment: Not asked about keystore password, not asked for adding github to known hosts list. 
Screenshots posted in update to post.

Comment: The screenshot shows that on the command line you used `https`, not `ssh`. Does choosing the protocol `https` instead of `ssh` work in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, playing with Visual Studio Code I stumbled on the same problem and was able to fix it, so I tried to apply solution to Eclipe and it started working for me.

Not sure why the original problem started, but now I found at least a workaround and can use Git from the Eclipse.

To remind what I had in Eclipse:

[image]

> org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Invalid remote: origin
>       at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.fetch.FetchOperationUI.execute(FetchOperationUI.java:106)
>       at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.fetch.FetchOperationUI$1.runInWorkspace(FetchOperationUI.java:123)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
>   Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.InvalidRemoteException: Invalid remote: origin
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:136)
>       at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.FetchOperation.run(FetchOperation.java:134)
>       at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.fetch.FetchOperationUI.execute(FetchOperationUI.java:103)
>       ... 3 more
>   Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.NoRemoteRepositoryException: git XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX: Permission denied (publickey).
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.cleanNotFound(TransportGitSsh.java:208)
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshFetchConnection.(TransportGitSsh.java:288)
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.openFetch(TransportGitSsh.java:161)
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:136)
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:122)
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1138)
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:130)

The solution was to start SSH agent first (to avoid asking passphrase) and then in the same shell session start Eclipse. Without any changes in Eclipse error gone and IDE started reaching repository.

So, the steps would be:

1. Open shell session (`cmd.exe`)
2. Start SSH agent (`start-ssh-agent.cmd`)
3. [In the same shell session] Start Eclipse (`eclipse.exe`)